# Thermal expansion of two bolts

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, atomic-physics, thermal-conductivity

[image: Bolts]

I have this question asking me about the thermal expansions of two bolts, a steel one, and a brass one. I have the equation:

$\ (\delta L/L)/T = \alpha $

I don't understand how I can use this equation to manipulate the temperature for the two bolts simultaneously, as opposed to the temperature required to expand each individual bolt by 5 $\mu$m. Is this even the correct equation? Or is there another that I should be using.

What I have done is rearranged for T:

$\ (\delta L/L)/\alpha = T$

Then, using the individual values for $\delta$L = 5$\mu$m L= 0.01 m and the $\alpha$ for steel to get $T=45.5^\circ C$ and similarly, for Brass, to get $T=8.77^\circ C$. This obviously cannot be correct, considering, using this method, the $T_0=27^\circ C$ has not been taken into consideration.

Any help would be good. Thanks.

Comment: The total length for the expansion is $5 \mu m$, so you will want to add the expansion of the steel with the expansion of the brass. Also I believe you have $\Delta T$, not $T$. I also saw that the units for $\alpha _{br}$ is incorrectly stated as $°C$ and not $°C^{-1}$.

Comment: The incorrect units are within the image made by the creator of the question. By adding the expansions, I assume you mean add the two coefficients of linear expansion together?

Comment: That will not work. What I mean is $\delta L_{st}+\delta L_{br}=5.0μm$.

Comment: So are you implying: 

$((\delta L_st + \delta L_Br) / L)/ \alpha = \Delta T $

Clearly I must not understand where you are coming from, considering both $\alpha$ are different.

Comment: The equation is more complex; give me a moment and I'll post it.

Comment: $(\delta L_{st}/L_{st})/\alpha _{st}\ =\ ((5.0\mu m - \delta L_{st})/L_{br})/\alpha _{br}$

Comment: Using this for $\delta L_st$ I get: 
$\delta L_st = 1.196*10^{-6}$ 
then this means:
$\delta L_Br = (5-1.196)*10^{-6} = 3.804*10 ^{-6}$ 
Using these to calculate T then gives a difference of about four degrees between the two using their respective values in the equation given, I still am unsure of where I go wrong.

Comment: What is wrong with a change of 4°? The gap is about as wide as a hair, so it wouldn't take a lot of heat to expand the bolts to fill the gap.